# Does trigger.io support blackberry?

Tags: trigger.io

Does trigger.io support blackberry? If no, are there any plans to support it.

Comment: No, there are no immediate plans to support it since we've had few requests for it. We're open to pulling it forward though if we see enough interest... email support@trigger.io to discuss

Answer (score 3):

In terms of mobile, they currently support:

- **iOS 4+** (both iPhone and iPad)
- **Android 2.0+**
- **Windows Phone***

I don't know whether they plan to support BlackBerry, as there is no such thing as a public roadmap.

*not sure about the minimum version

Source: https://trigger.io/pricing/ (See "All Platforms" on the "Go Pro" plan)